# Converting data into dictionary of Dictionaries in python

Tags: python, json, dictionary

I am reading a file in python using a key value pair, for example

```
Mac:aaaa
IP:bbbbb
Name:dddd

Mac:wwwww
IP:fffff
Name:sssss

Mac:hhhh
IP:ddd
Name:fff
```

so, my query is, I need to build a dictionary of dictionaries for the above data so as to format it as json.

Comment: You need to add a sample of what Python structure you expect *at the very least*; a dictionary of dictionaries needs keys, but you didn't tell us anything about where those keys would come from, for example.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you mean a list of dictionaries, not a dictionary of dictionaries

```
from operator  import methodcaller
fdata = open("data.txt").read().split()
split2 = methodcaller("split",":")
print map(dict, zip(*[iter(map(split2, fdata))]*3))
```

is a fun way to do it ;)

however if you did want a dictionary of dictionaries as your title suggests you can simply

```
dict(enumerate(map(dict, zip(*[iter(map(split2, fdata.split()))]*3))))
```

[edited to be more pep-8 compliant :P ]